# How can I disable verbatim insertion on a terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, copy-paste

I recently moved back from using mostly mac to using mostly linux. When I want to paste something, I usually press <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd>, and seeing it fail makes me realize, that I meant to press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + V</kbd> and press those buttons as well. However, this results some extra characters placed both at the beginning and at the end of the command, meaning that I have to actively search back and delete the inserted crap.

For example, inserting `https://superuser.com/questions/ask` produces:

```bsh
^[[200~https://superuser.com/questions/ask~
```

I learned that <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> performs something called "verbatim insert", a functionality, that I have never ever used during my many years of using a terminal. Is there a way of disabling this functionality altogether? It would be nice to have <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> rebound to paste, but having it just not insert weird content all over the place would great.

I am using Konsole (18.04.0), zsh (5.7.1), but all other terminal applications I tested behaved identically.

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/311065/108618) and [this](https://superuser.com/q/1532688/432690).

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski, you solved my problem perfectly :)